# Change Authority when using IdentityServerAuthentication

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I use IdentityServerAuthentication:

```
services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "some_url";
                ...
            });
```

But my authorization server can change, and I`ll get the new configuration.

How can I change Authority during runtime?

Comment: Is this for the multitenancy purpose? Gives us more context please.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius my authorization server can change, I get new configuration and I need to update it

Comment: Can you not put the url in the appsettings.json? Does it truly need to change at runtime dynamically?

Comment: How will you get the new configuration during runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided my problem using `IOptionsMonitorCache<IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions>.`
I call "Clear" method and then it call configuration code again in

```
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
        {
           // this code will be called again. I use setting provider here. 
        });
```

Comment: Can you explain or share the complete code on how to do it?